# Raspberry Pi camera image color are diffrent from real colors

Tags: raspberry-pi, camera, raspberry-pi4

I am new to Raspberry Pi and I am using a 5 megapixel Raspberry Pi camera version 1.3 and I have taken pictures with it. But the color of the pictures taken is different from the actual color of the object. I wanted to know why this is happening? And how to make the images closer to the real color?
Thanks

Raspberry Pi camera image:

[image]

Actual image(using a phone)

[image]

my Raspberry Pi camera Config:

```
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import time
import cv2
import operationFramesFuncShape
camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (980, 480)
camera.framerate = 32
camera.rotation = -90
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(980, 480))
# allow the camera to warmup
time.sleep(0.1)

g = camera.awb_gains
camera.awb_mode = 'off'
camera.awb_gains = g
oclass = operationFramesFuncShape.objectFrameClass()
for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
  # grab the raw NumPy array representing the image, then initialize the timestamp
  # and occupied/unoccupied text
  image = frame.array
```

Comment: It looks like you haven't calibrated your camera. This is not really a programming question, and even if it were, it would be too broad for a concise answer. There are plenty of guides on the web, and you might ask on [raspberrypi.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try to adjust white balance?
Please try: camera.awb_gains = (1.5, 1.5) and adjust valuse to your needs.

Also why you assign g = camera.awb_gains
and then camera.awb_gains = g ?

Comment: Thanks @tomasz-jędrzejczyk, Finally i set `camera.awb_gains = (1.8, 1.4)` and it solved.